# Pivot table: Group by date as decades

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a date column in Excel having values from "11/15/1989 to 12/21/2014". I want this column in pivot table Rows field group by decades as 1991-2000.  I tried using Group field but it allows only to group by years or days not by decades.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: can you add an assist column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your original data or add an assist column to the pivot table, copy

`=FLOOR(B1,10)`

in A1 (presuming your dates were in A and you inserted a column before it)

It should round down to the nearest specified multiple, in this case base 10 for decades

Comment: if the solution answered your question, let us know by marking the answer as "accepted". All the best!

Comment: Randomly stumbled upon this today, and appreciate a simple solution by looking at the problem from a different angle. thanks!